# KivyMD таблица (android)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Написал приложение все работает хорошо, до перехода на форму с таблицей. В отладке все работает хорошо, но после сборки buildozer под android, попадаю на страницу вижу таблицу и через секунды 2-3 приложение вылетает.

```
class ResultScreen(Screen):
    
    def on_enter(self):
        self.load_table()
        
    def load_table(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint={'center_y': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Head 1", dp(30)),
                ("Head 2", dp(30)),
                ("Head 3", dp(30)),
                ("Head 4", dp(30)), ],
            row_data=[
                (f"{i + 1}", "C", "C++", "JAVA", "Python")
                for i in range(50)], )
        self.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        return layout
```